# how to put errors in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

so this is my console log

```
{
"name": ["The name field is required."],
"type": ["The type field is required."],
"ceiling_amount": ["The ceiling amount field is required."]
}
```

how can i put errors in my html like this

```
console.log(res)    
if(res.hasOwnProperty('errors')){
    for(var field in res.errors){
        var fieldname = field;
        var input = $("[name=\""+fieldname+"\"]");
        input.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error')
        input.after('<span class="help-block">'+res.errors[field]+"</span>")
    }
}else{
    window.location.href = res.redirectTo;
}
```

but this html i use .done() here

but my question is how can i put errors when i use .fail() and thats my response json?

Comment: it thats your console.log, there is no property errors

Comment: also if it fails you dont have a response json, it depends on the status codes you send by the backend

Comment: im still confused, im sorry.. can you explain further?

Comment: Can it be better to handle validation in frontend with some scripts ?

Comment: the error or fail callback will only be fired if the server responses with an error code like 500 internal server error or 404 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, there's no error property there, but you can use the `.error()` function of your ajax. Here's my typical ajax request that I often use:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: myData,
        error: function (data){
            // here's your error data
            if( data.status == 422){ // this is the status code that laravel 
                                     //  sends when a validation failed: 422
                                     //    (Unprocessable Entity)
              console.warn(data.responseJSON);
            }else{
              console.warn("this is some other error.");
            }
        },
        success: function (data){
            // do something; status code = 200
        }
    }).complete(function (response){
        // do something; regardless of the status code
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful, you can upvote or accept it if this answers your question.